# Как вывести представление типа данных MySQL в двоичном виде?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Пробовал так:

```
select cast(convert('1900-01-02 00:00:01.000000', datetime(6)) AS BINARY)
```

Получил такое:

```
4957484845484945485032484858484858484946484848484848
```

Это просто коды символов по ASCII, но datetime(6) занимает 8 байт и мне нужно именно содержимое этих 8 байт. convert вместо cast не помог. Интересует именно datetime(6). Такой подход работал для MS SQL Server, но для MySQL почему-то поведение отличается.

Comment: Попробуйте кастить сначало в double (float) а за тем в binary, тогда, я думаю получите двоичное представление дробного числа. `cast(cast ( convert('1900-01-02 00:00:01.000000', datetime(6)) as double) as binary)` как-то так (нет под рукой mysql)

Comment: @nick_n_a double нельзя в cast/convert использовать, там только ограниченный набор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось открыть .idb файл HEX-редактором и найти там нужные 8 байт.

В даблице была запись: `'2020-05-05 23:18:36.123457'`, для которой первые 5 байт по официальной документации закодированы как `99A64B74A4`. Оставшиеся три байта были найдены в HEX-представлении файла таблицы и оказались `01E241`, т.е. первые 4 бита - дырка, фактически, лидирующие нули.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time) должно быть 5+3 байта

получается что нужно сделать так:

```
select 
    d as datetime
    , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d) as timestamp
    , TRUNCATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d)*1000000, 0) as ULong
    , HEX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d)*1000000) as `hex(ULong)`
FROM (
    SELECT '2020-05-05 23:18:36.123457' AS d UNION
    SELECT '2020-05-05 23:18:36.123458' AS d UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-15 12:01:01' AS d UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-15 12:01:01.001' AS d UNION
    SELECT '2015-01-15 12:01:01.000001' AS d
) v

'2020-05-05 23:18:36.123457' > 5A4EC5A33A141
'2020-05-05 23:18:36.123458' > 5A4EC5A33A142
```